# Add component in .ism using Iscmdbld.exe

Tags: cmd, installshield

I'm building InstallShield project using cmd tool- ***iscmdbld.exe.*** I want to specify the build directory from where it is taking files, for that I need to add components and folders. 
*Is there any command which does that?* 
what not working is:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\System\IsCmdBld.exe" -p C:\InstallShield\APEXDFZ\APEXDFZ.ism -v -z "AddComponent=C\build\MyVota" -z "AddComponent=C\build\MyVota1"`

Last **-z** arguments are not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-z is for properties, path Variables use -l. However, I do not believe you can add components using IsCmdBld.exe. When you add files to a component in InstallShield - it will give it a path variable, "PATH_TO_FILES="C:\whatever\path" if your files are being built in "C:\My\Build\Folder" then you would just:

"...\IsCmdBld.exe" -p "..\APEXDFZ.ism" -l "PATH_TO_FILES=C:\My\Build\Folder"

Now - I am a little confused to your question about adding components. You could add all files with exclude/include options by using a dynamic file linking where it will grab everything in that folder even sub-folders and change the path on the cmdline same way.

However, there is a way to dynamically add components, you would want to use InstallShield's automation interface "IswiAutoXX" where XX is the version of IS you have installed - and not related to the actual version...something in the 20's. Hope this helps.